# SQL Server 2008 how to get top record from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have tables called `News`, `Sports`, `Technology`, `Articles`...etc , each table has ID, Title, Content, Image, Date .. The `ID` is the primary key in each table, and each table has no relationships, no joins no any thing, they are in the same database but separated.

What I want is to select the last added record from each table (just 1 record from each table) assuming that I ordered them by `ID DESC`, to bind them to datalist (Latest/Shuffle).

So what SQL query statement should I use ?

The records in DataList should be like this:

```
    News_ID             News_Title             News_Content            News_Date
    Technology_ID       Technology_Title       Technology_Content      Technology_Date
    SPorts_ID           Sports_Title           Sports_Content          Sports_Date

and so on....
```

Any pointers ??

My SQL skills are not so good. Any help is greatly appreciated.

regards.

Comment: If each table has the same structure, it sounds like your data model is wrong - there ought to be a single table with the same structure you currently have and an additional column that will contain one of "News", "Technology", "Sports", etc. Your current query isn't *too* tricky to solve with the current structure but over time you'll find that other queries are more complex to write because part of your *data* has ended up embedded in the table *names* (i.e. it's been put in the metadata for the database instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 
    News_ID, News_Title, News_Content, News_Date 
from News 
order by News_ID desc

union all

select top 1 
    Technology_ID, Technology_Title, Technology_Content, Technology_Date
from Technology 
order by Technology_ID desc

union all

select top 1 
    Sports_ID, Sports_Title, Sports_Content, Sports_Date
from Sports 
order by Sports_ID desc
```

Comment: can put all of this in one statment ?? to be able to use it in asp.net and bind the datalist from code ??

Comment: @AmeerA.Lawi 
The query returns one result set. Have you tried to use it? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM News
ORDER BY News_ID DESC
```